# Terraform AKS Cluster Deployment Error: Unauthorized and Kubernetes provider unreachable

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks

I'm trying to automate the deployment of an Azure AKS cluster and configuring a kubernetes cluster using Terraform, following an [example](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-aks/tree/main/examples/named_cluster). I'm encountering issues with the RBAC configuration and the authorization of my Kubernetes provider. In a separate project, when I call the AKS module without the additional Azure RBAC configuration, it works fine. However, in my current project, I receive the following error:

```
module.kubernetes-config.kubernetes_namespace.test: Creating...
module.kubernetes-config.helm_release.nginx_ingress: Creating...

╷
│ Error: Unauthorized
│ 
│   with module.kubernetes-config.kubernetes_namespace.test,
│   on ../kubernetes-cluster/cluster.tf line 14, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test":
│   14: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
│ 
│   with module.kubernetes-config.helm_release.nginx_ingress,
│   on ../kubernetes-cluster/cluster.tf line 59, in resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress":
│   59: resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
│ 
╵
```

Here is my kubernetes code:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.aks_cluster.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = module.aks_cluster.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.aks_cluster.cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
}

module "kubernetes-config" {
  depends_on   = [module.aks_cluster]
  source       = "../kubernetes-resources"
  kubeconfig   = module.aks_cluster.kube_config_raw
```

kubernetes-resources:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.0.3"
    }
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = ">= 2.1.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test" {
  metadata {
    name = "test"
  }
...
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "test" {
  metadata {
    name      = "test"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.test.metadata.0.name
  }
  
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name = "nginx-ingress-controller"

  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress-controller"

  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "ClusterIP"
  }
}

resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  content  = var.kubeconfig
  filename = "${path.root}/kubeconfig"
}
```

Is there something wrong with the RBAC configuration in the example? How can I fix the authorization issue for my Kubernetes provider? Please let me know if you need more information or additional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the error by using `kube_admin_config` in order to authorize the kubernetes provider with RBAC

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.host
  username               = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.username
  password               = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.password
  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.host
    username               = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.username
    password               = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.password
    client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.default.kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
}
```

Thanks to [Justin VanWinkle](https://www.kubernet.dev/terraform-and-aad-rbac-integration-for-aks/) for the solution

Answer (score 0):

As per this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/hybrid/known-issues-security#kubectl-logs-return--error--you-must-be-logged-in-to-the-server--the-server-has-asked-for-the-client-to-provide-credentials%E2%80%94):

> AKS hybrid rotates core Kubernetes certificates every 4 days, but
> sometimes the Kubernetes API server doesn't immediately reload its
> client certificate for communication with kubelet when the
> certificates update.

Check if you have kubernetes certificates updated, if not update them using the method from the above doc.

Also check [AKS cluster with service principal credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/update-credentials#update-aks-cluster-with-service-principal-credentials) and check if you have [Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#azure-kubernetes-service-cluster-admin-role).

For RBAC follow this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac).